# Javascript. Системный терминал

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли как нибудь обойти эти "**Соображения безопасности**" и с помощью javascript кода открыть системный терминал?
**Для чего?О_о**
Пищу учебное приложение и хочу сделать его десктопным, с помощью **Electron(на основе браузера Chromium)**.
 Это приложение должно иметь доступ к системному терминалу, для того чтобы можно было запускать **сборщик проектов GULP**(а конкретно, отдельные его **task'и**).
 ----В приложении есть некие кнопки, функция которых запускать определенные **gulp task'и**, то-есть при нажатии на одну из кнопок, передавать её параметры(допустим **gulp start**) в строку терминала и запускать его.
Возможно ли вообще это сделать? Или может есть другой вариант запуска **GULP'a** в браузере?

Comment: Браузер никак не даст доступа до терминала или папке "Porno" в системном каталоге. Это основа "соображений по безопасности".

Comment: @Other и даже не предусмотрена в браузере волшебная кнопочка для отключения этой безопасности ?

Comment: Нет, этих возможностей даже никто не писал, куда там отключение. Разве что использовать 0-day, но это взлом, не подходит для нормальной работы.

Comment: @Denisoed, если отключение будет доступно вам, то оно будет доступно и каждому встречному-поперечному взломщику-ботоводу-рекламщику-прочей нечисти.

Comment: @Arhad, это ничего не меняет - ботнет можно у себя устроить только. У остальных защита включена была бы.

Comment: @Arhad у меня сейчас пример для подражания это редактор кода Atom, который работает на основе chromium. В нем есть как раз таки свой терминал, вернее плагин. Мне всего лишь запустить бы gulp через браузер и я был бы доволен

Comment: @Other и кстати кто сейчас "Porno" хранит в компе? наверное в черной папке без названия, как раньше видео касеты на видик

Comment: Ну я храню. Пытаюсь обучить домашнего дворецкого понимать **чем** является папка.

Comment: ну так если у тебя уже есть пример плагина который работает - просто посмотри его исходники

Comment: У меня нет электрона чтоб проверить и устанавливать лень, но электрон ведь основан на базе nodejs, у него ведь есть апи для внешних процессов! [http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/process/](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/process/)  [https://nodejs.org/api/process.html](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html)

Comment: Всем спасибо =)

Comment: Electron не браузер. Поскольку Electron-приложение пользователь сам устанавливает на собственную машину, давая явное согласие, исполняемому в его рамках коду позволяется куда больше.

Comment: @D-side я понимаю что он не браузер =) Тут дело ни в самом  Electron'e, а в том какую он предоставляет оболочку для запуска приложения. Как мы знаем эта оболочка - есть браузер chromium.

Comment: Мне таким заниматься не приходилось, но вот что я нагуглил за 5 минут: 
https://discuss.atom.io/t/execute-shell-commands-from-application/20013/2

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Спасибо =)